# Finding missing dependencies in distributed ArcGIS Python toolbox?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox

I am developing a Python Toolbox that uses a few external libraries (`ogr/gdal`, `matplotlib`, `shapely`, `reportlab` among others) which files I have directly copied in the same folder as my toolbox .py, as recommended in Esri's [A simple approach for including 3rd party Python libraries with your scripts](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/06/a-simple-approach-for-including-3rd-party-python-libraries-with-your-scripts/). It works just fine on my computer, but when I run this tool on another computer, I get an `ImportError`. It's very likely that the libraries are the reason for that error.

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Moreover, I don't get the `ImportError` the same way from ArcGIS10.0 or ArcGIS10.1 (10.0: only get the error without any additional message; 10.1: get the error where it worked fine in the previous version), which worries me a bit because this really looks like a singular configuration dependent problem.

How do I find the missing dependencies in my current distribution and ensure that the tool which I distribute will work on every computer with a fresh ArcGIS installation?

I have tried what I consider the usual ways to solve that problem:

- Run the script outside ArcMap to debug it but I did not get much more information.
- Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the missing DLLs but when I try to profile ArcMap, [Dependency Walker stops running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832936/profiling-x86-executable-with-dependency-walker-hangs-on-windows-7-x64).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a matter of *missing* dependencies, it's a matter of *incorrectly versioned* dependencies. ArcGIS 10.0 runs Python 2.6, while 10.1 runs 2.7. Any library with a C extension will need to be bundled with your toolbox for the correct version of Python depending on the target version of ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what explains the differences between the 2 versions. It makes me wonder something else: will the error be the same for a missing library and for an incorrectly versioned one? I will explore that. However I still have this ImportError occurring on other computers but not on mine (with the same version).

Comment: You'll get the same error _type_ (`ImportError`) but the error _message_ will be different.

Comment: Alright, that answers one problem. Do you have any additional insights on the missing libraries (or else if I'm wrong) issue?

Comment: In your script tools, you may need to add the directory of the current script to `sys.path` so Python can find your bundled copies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it did not work (it didn't change the outcome at all)...